Create GCP folder with Terraform only if it does not exist
I have a key - value input with information about GCP projects that need to be created. With information like the name, GCP folder that the project should go in etc.
I want in my terraform code to create the folder of the project if it does not exist.
With a code like this:
module "project-factory" {
  source            = "terraform-google-modules/project-factory/google"
  for_each          = local.projects
  name              = each.key
  org_id            = each.value.org_id
  folder_id         = google_folder.team[each.key].name
  .
  .
  .
}

resource "google_folder" "team" {
  for_each     = local.projects
  display_name = each.value.folder
  parent       = var.parent
}

That creates the problem of course, that if multiple projects have the same folder to go in, the creation to fail because the folder is already created.
I guess I can do some - unwanted - magic with running scripts and importing the folders in my tf.state, but is there any clever solution for the problem?
Thank you!

When multiple projects use the same folder, the folder creation can fail because Terraform tries to create it multiple times. One efficient and cleaner solution is to deduplicate the folders and ensure that each folder is created only once.
Use Terraform’s for_each combined with a set of unique folder names.
locals {
  unique_folders = tomap({
    for project_key, project in local.projects :
    project.folder => project
  })
}


resource "google_folder" "team" {
  for_each     = local.unique_folders
  display_name = each.key
  parent       = var.parent
}


module "project-factory" {
  source            = "terraform-google-modules/project-factory/google"
  for_each          = local.projects
  name              = each.key
  org_id            = each.value.org_id
  # Lookup folder ID from the created folders
  folder_id         = google_folder.team[each.value.folder].name
  # Other configurations...
}

